# "packageName" with GHC.Generics

Tags: haskell, ghc-generics

I have a class that provides a globally unique identifier for types:

```
class Named a where
 nameOf :: a -> (String,String,String) -- (Package, Module, Identifier)
 default nameOf :: (Generic a, Named' (Rep a)) => a -> (String,String,String)
 nameOf = nameOf' . from
```

which almost works:

```
>>> data D = C
>>> instance Named D
>>> nameOf C
("","Main","D")
```

but I can't get the datatype's package with `GHC.Generics`:

```
class Named' f where  nameOf' :: f a -> (String,String,String)
instance (Datatype t) => Named' (M1 D t f) where nameOf' d = ("", moduleName d, datatypeName d)
```

Can I? The GUI's not really "globally" unique without the package.

btw, I know that with `Data.Typeable` I can write:

```
>>> import Data.Typeable
>>> :set -XDeriveDataTypeable
>>> let nameOf = (\t -> (tyConPackage t, tyConModule t, tyConName t)) . typeRepTyCon . typeRep
>>> data D = C deriving Typeable
>>> nameOf (Proxy :: Proxy D)
("interactive" "Ghci3" "D")
```

Which is what I may do. But I'm curious about `GHC.Generics`.

Comment: AFAIK no. But it's impossible to have same module twice in the same program (even from different packages).

Comment: [1] even with `PackageImports`? (haven't used it, just heard about it)

Comment: [2] what does "program" mean, in this context? what if you import two different modules from different packages, which each import the "same" module which are from different packages, neither of which packages  (the latter two) you directly depend on. does that code not compile? And thanks!

Comment: Seems that with `PackageImports` you can import the same module from different packages, even into the same module: https://gist.github.com/phadej/8b628d579ddf6958d937 Didn't ever tried to do anything like that!

Comment: I created a [ghc ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10030#ticket) let's see what more wise people respond.

Answer (score 1):

So far it's impossible to get package name using Generics. There is a [GHC feature request -ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/17) now. It was straightforward to implement, but let's see when the patch lands release version.