# Load a module in GHCi by module name when module name doesn't match file name

Tags: haskell, import, module, ghci

Suppose I am given a source file called `MyModule.hs` and inside it the module declaration is `module My.Module where ...` (note: *not* `module MyModule where ...`).

I am not permitted to alter this source file or change the directory structure where the file resides.

From reading [some docs about importing modules in GHCi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html), it looks like there are ways to import *by file name* (e.g. either `import` or `:load`), but not any ways to specify a module name that will be searched for in all files of the local directory.

Is there a way to import `My.Module` in GHCi without doing it by specifying the file's name (only the module name) and without installing it (e.g. not building it with `cabal`, just quickly tossing it into GHCi by module name)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't where the name contains a dot, as per the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#search-path)

> For each of these directories, it tries appending basename.extension to the directory, and checks whether the file exists. The value of basename is the module name with dots replaced by the directory separator ('/' or '\', depending on the system), and extension is a source extension (hs, lhs)...

The key part being

> The value of basename is the module name with dots replaced by the directory separator ('/' or '\', depending on the system)

So your module name of `My.Module` will be searched for as `My/Module.hs`.  You would need to have a directory structure like

```
project/
    My/
        Module.hs
    project.cabal
```

And from the folder `project` you could run

```
$ cabal repl
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
> import My.Module
```

You *can* do this if your file is named `MyModule.hs` and your module name is `MyModule`, but it's just a special case of the rule above.

There are good reasons for this, namely that it enforces a structure to simplify your project structure and GHC's search algorithm.  If this rule wasn't in place, what would stop me from having

```
project/
    MyModule1.hs
    MyModule2.hs
```

where both `.hs` files had the module declaration `My.Module`?  Which one would be correct to load in GHCi if I ran `import My.Module`?  By specifying what the filename and path is, you immediately know that the module `X.Y.Z.W.Q.R.S.T` is at the path `X/Y/Z/W/Q/R/S/T.hs`, no searching required.  It reduces a lot of the ambiguity that could occur with looser module name specifications.

Comment: In the final example you give, I think the question of which one is the correct module to load is trivial: whichever is found first on the search path or in search order. That's how this is resolved in many other languages. I'm not saying that is a pro or con w.r.t. your answer -- just that I see it as a trivial problem and think allowing people to re-use the same module name if they prefer seems fine to me. Preventing it doesn't really 'protect' you from anything.

Comment: Also, the docs about all this suggest that it is perfectly valid & reasonable to do many things in Haskell: define more than one module per file is OK; define one module across more than one file is OK (exactly by re-using the same module name and ensuring no declared names conflict); and naming the module something different than the file name is also OK (you can still import it as a package, or in GHCi with the file name). All these are listed in the docs I linked in my question. So while mapping modules to file paths might be common practice, it's certainly not enforced by the language.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr If you just use the first one found on the path, what ordering method are you using?  Unicode ordering?  Ok, so now one of them always gets loaded and the other does not, how do you then load the second module?  Also, I know of no language that actually does what you say.  In .NET languages you can't, although the filename has nothing to do with the module structure. In Python the filename is exactly the module name, you don't get to declare your module name.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr The example in the docs you linked to really only applies to the `Main` module and using the `:load` command. In fact, that documentation states "Question: How does GHC find the filename which contains module M? Answer: it looks for the file M.hs, or M.lhs. This means that for most modules, **the module name must match the filename. If it doesn't, GHCi won't be able to find it.**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: "There is one exception to this general rule: when you load a program with :load, or specify it when you invoke ghci, you can give a filename rather than a module name. This filename is loaded if it exists, and it may contain any module you like. This is particularly convenient if you have several Main modules in the same directory and you can't call them all Main.hs." - The exception is that in GHCi you can use `:load` on a filename specifically, but this is an implementation feature in GHCi, it is not part of the language of Haskell.  The Haskell language specifies a file structure.

Comment: ["There is no formal connection between a Haskell module and the file system that would (typically) support it. In particular, there is no connection between module names and file names, and more than one module could conceivably reside in a single file (one module may even span several files)."](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Ok, so the Haskell language doesn't necessarily care, but [GHC does](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#hierarchical-modules).  If you want to use it in GHCi, you'll have to follow GHCi's rules.  Also, the sentence before what you quoted is "Module names are alphanumeric and must begin with an uppercase letter."  You wouldn't be able to have the module `My.Module` without GHC's standard at all.  This is actually a deviation from Haskell98.

Comment: The Python trick you linked to is not renaming a module either.  The module name there would still be `oldmodule` according to the `__name__` variable, but it would be imported elsewhere as `newmodule`.  Initially, the interpreter still sees it as `oldmodule` during the first import, but then the module is inserted into the `sys.modules` dictionary under a new name.  This doesn't change the name of the module, it just changes the search path at runtime.  Python does go with the first instance found in its search path, though.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr IMHO clear, straightforward and almost branchless search mechanism of GHC clearly simplifies reasoning about modules & filesystem connection. [With `PackageImports` you can already make some grey hair to your co-workers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159068/packagename-with-ghc-generics/28177069#) [(gist)](https://gist.github.com/phadej/8b628d579ddf6958d937). If you cannot alter the directory structure where file is, you can make a properly arranged "copy" of it with symlinks.

Comment: @phadej I am not making normative claims about whether this version of importing is good or bad. I'm not interested in whether it is good or bad, just whether it can be done. We have to assume the symlink approach won't work: suppose there is already some other file sitting in the directory path "My/Module.hs" and it is *also* named My.Module. We want to import from the other file MyModule.hs (that also has My.Module as the module name despite not residing at that path), and say the modules were set up this way intentionally; the namespaces don't conflict and it's desired for them to overlap.

Comment: Similar to the way folks sometimes do qualified imports like `import Data.Thing as T; import Data.Thing.Stuff as T, ...`, having taken care to ensure `Data.Thing` and `Data.Thing.Stuff` don't conflict. Since Haskell permits modules to reside across more than one source file, someone may have created `module My.Module where ...` residing in file `src/My/Module.hs` and then later wanted to extend it by placing code in `src/MyModule.hs` using `module My.Module where ...`. Again, not at all saying it's good, just saying it can be done and you can inherit it and need to import it in ghci.